# A desktop app that lets me search for music (in an interesting way)?  

Tags: search, music, exploration, software

A while back I came across this amazing Mac app that let me search for music by hovering my mouse over clusters of spatially organized files. As you hover, you'd hear snippets of the music (long enough to know what's playing).

I can't remember what the name is... Anyone know?

While I'm at it, do you know of any interesting apps that let you explore/search your music/sounds on your computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [sound torch](http://soundtorch.com/) it sounds like the same app that you describing but this one runs on windows only. sound torch works nicely but it takes an age to create the database for searching.

Comment: he redsonic, do you have any idea how the sound torch app works? it takes ages because it analyses the audio bit by bit? audio descriptor algorithms can be very complex, but i still wonder how sound torch works..

Comment: @Arnoud Traa - I don't actually know how it works but my guess would be that it does an fft analysis of each file then does a comparison of each to make the graphical 'sound map'. but please don't quote me on that.  

Comment: let me just quote you on that :) thanks redsonic